# Use double in float requiring function

Tags: c#, parsing

From a textfile I read a value, X.

```
XCOORD = -75.015
```

I get it like this, and convert it to a double.

```
    var dic = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")
      .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '=' }))
      .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());

    string X = dic["XCOORD"];
    double GivenX = Convert.ToDouble(X);
```

I then use my function like so:

```
WriteFloat(pointerx, (float)GivenX);
```

Unfortunately, the function can't read the value properly. Because it does work if I simply do:

```
WriteFloat(pointerx, -75.015f);
```

I think it doesn't read the symbols - and/or . is there any idea on how to get this done? As requested, I printed out the value of X:

```
mRef.showInfo(Convert.ToString(GivenX));
```

It shows me: -75015, without the . I printed this after converting it to double.
If I put it in the text file like this: `XCOORD = -75.015f`. It crashes my entire program.

WriteFloat function:

```
public void WriteFloat(long Address, float Value)
        {
            WriteProcessMemory(GetProcessHandle(), Address, BitConverter.GetBytes(Value), 4);
        }
```

Currently, I've found out that before I convert it to a double. It prints X out fine: -75.015. After converting it to a double it is: -75015. It misses the . after -75.

Comment: Please add the  code for the function.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?  What does `X` look like after the dictionary look up?  What is the value of `GivenX` after the `Convert.ToDouble` call?  By the way, you are probably better off with `double.TryParse` than `Convert.ToDouble`.  What do you mean by "the function can't read the value properly"

Comment: Are you 100% sure `x == "-75.015f"`?

Comment: The code should work (and -75.015f will definitely not ignore the - and the .) so something else must be wrong.  Set a breakpoint in your code.  See what you get for string X before converting it to a double - it's probably not valid.  Then see what double GivenX is - it's probably null.

Comment: I will edit to show what X looks like, however adding the nature of the WriteFloat function doesn't seem necessary as it simply requires a float. I'm also sure It's correctly in the textfile.

Comment: Define "the function can't read the value properly", are you getting an error? Wrong value?

Comment: Just curious, you go through and define everything as a double, then cast as a float... any reason it's not defined as a float?

Comment: Trey, I tried this first. Parsing it to a float immediately, not using it as a double. That didn't work for me either.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the dictionary lookup line of code.  Find out what the Dictionary looks like.  Then after executing that line, look at `X`, then, after executing another line, look at `GivenX`.  You need to learn to debug your code!

Comment: It would help to see the code for the function you are referring to.

Comment: You are making calls to methods we can't see: `WriteFloat` and `showInfo`. Show them.

Comment: I have debugged my code, after every single line. I will add the function to the post.

Comment: ... so the error is coming out of WriteProcessMemory??

Comment: To be exact, there isn't an error exactly. It works, it just writes a different value than I give in my textfile. That's why I was thinking it might not be reading one of the symbols correctly. It does write..

Comment: This is a case where if you made your own test routines, you would have been able to figure this out fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really answer, but it answers a lot of the comments.  And, it won't fit in a comment

I created a simple text file that looks like:

```
XCOORD = -75.015
POSITIVE = 25.123
WHOLE = 123
```

Then I took your code and fleshed it out to read all the keys/values in that file and write the results out:

```
 public static void ConvertTheFloats()
 {
     var dic = File.ReadAllLines("ConvertFloatsData.txt")
         .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '=' }))
         .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());

     var keys = dic.Keys;
     foreach (var key in keys)
     {
         string x = dic[key];
         if (float.TryParse(x, out var floatX))
         {
             Debug.WriteLine($"Success: Key: {key} - String Value: {x} - Float Value: {floatX}");
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.WriteLine($"Failed: Key: {key} - String Value: {x}");
         }
     }
 }
```

The result looks like:

```
Success: Key: XCOORD - String Value: -75.015 - Float Value: -75.015
Success: Key: POSITIVE - String Value: 25.123 - Float Value: 25.123
Success: Key: WHOLE - String Value: 123 - Float Value: 123
```

So, your parsing of the file works.  The dictionary gets keys and string representing floats (I didn't bother with doubles).  I can successfully convert them to floats.  The values match.

It appears that your issues are in code you haven't posted.

Comment: This helped me getting it to work, thanks! I've no clue where I made a mistake. But thanks!